# If a time series, which is a sum of some component time series, is spiking, how do I attribute the spike to the components

Tags: time-series, anomaly-detection

Let $X_t$ be a time series with $X_t = Y_t + Z_t$. At time $T$, $X_T$ "spikes"; that is to say, $X_{T-1}-X_T$ is over some critical threshold. I would like to assign some "contribution" to the spike to both $Y_T$ and $Z_T$, so that I can say something like "the spike is 90% driven by a corresponding spike in $Y_T$". Is there a standard way to do this?

What I've considered is using $\frac {Y_T - Y_{T-1}}{X_T - X_{t-1}}$ and $\frac {Z_T - Z_{T-1}}{X_T - X_{t-1}}$, but these don't seem perfect for a few reasons.

1. It's only in $[0,1]$ if both $Y$ and $Z$ increased, otherwise it might be negative or greater than 1.
2. (1) is compounded when there are more than two terms contributing to $Y$.

I've tried looking for any standard statistical techniques for this kind of "spike attribution", but have come up a bit dry. Are there any standard measures or techniques for this?

Comment: what exactly is the problem with the measure being outside of [0,1]? What would you propose to do in a situation where Y has a large positive spike and Z has a small negative spike, combining to give a moderate positive spike in X?

Comment: Because $dX_t = X_{t}-X_{t-1}=dY_t+dZ_t,$ you appear to be asking to decompose $dX_t$ into a linear combination of $dY_t$ and $dZ_t.$  Isn't that baked into your assumption?  The contributions are equal *by the very definition of $X.$* I suspect the way in which you have framed your problem might not convey the problem correctly.

Comment: When defining a spike as a large $X_{T-1}-X_T$, you are implicitly considering spikes of the first-difference series $\Delta X_t$. For the original series, a large $X_{T-1}-X_T$ may or may not look like a spike in the graph, but for $\Delta X_t$ it will.